Imputing NA values using Mice while also using a column 'Total' as a condition for the imputation R



ID
Year
Maths
Eng
Total




1
2010
20
15
35


1
2011
17
NA
40


2
2010
NA
NA
46


2
2011
NA
NA
39


3
2010
NA
15
41


3
2011
18
NA
43


4
2010
NA
15
NA


4
2011
NA
18
NA



Hello, I am trying to use the mice package to impute missing data like in an example table above.
I was wondering if there is a way to consider the column 'total' and impute/predict missing data for the subject column?
Currently I am able to impute but as you can guess, when I am doing the total of the imputed subject values, it is not adding up to the total already present in the original data.
Is there any way to mitigate this or another method I could use instead of MICE please?
This is the code I am using below.
mydata$Total <-  NULL

mydata.imp <- mice(data = mydata, m=5, maxit = 10, method = "cart", seed = 100)


Thank you

So, for example id==2 and year==2010, the imputed maths and eng must sum 46 - is that it?

@AdrianoMello Yes. For example when doing that I am getting maths 20 and eng 15 which does not add up to the sum 46. Any help would be very much appreciated. Thank you
